# Flow of code execution

Tags: javascript, angular

I am from a Java background. I started learning Angular2 a while back and working on it. In one of my projects, I have come across a situation which I cannot understand.

For my pagination implementation, I am taking the number of all tenders available in the database using Angular2 observables. After getting the value, I just log it into the console just to make sure the code works fine. But it prints undefined.

This is the relevant part of my code.

```
this.getNumberOfAllTenders();
console.log("number of tenders = "+this._numberOfAllTenders);
```

Here is the output

> number of tenders = undefined

following is the method which takes the number of tenders from the back end

```
 getNumberOfAllTenders(){
         this._tendersService.getNumberOfAllTenders().
            subscribe(

            numberOfAllTenders => this._numberOfAllTenders = numberOfAllTenders,
            error => this._error_all_numbers = error

            );
            console.log('+++++++++++++++++++ number of tenders in db = '+this._numberOfAllTenders);
    }
```

In above code snippet also, there is a line to print to the console. The output of that too is undefined. But that line is executed once the variable is assigned the value obtained from the back end.

I am sure that, my service code gets the value from the backend. I tried printing it on my template. It prints the correct value.

Now my question is, why it prints 'undefined' in the console. Those variables are assigned values correctly. From what I know, once the function to assign the values to variables is called, the values should be available for the latter parts of the code.

Please clarify me on this. is the flow of code execution different in Angular2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prints `undefined` because observables run async and thus they aren't finished running by the time your `console` commands run.  If you wanted to use `console.log` on the return value of the observable, you could move the `console` command to inside the `subscribe` function:

```
this._tendersService.getNumberOfAllTenders().
            subscribe(
              numberOfAllTenders => {
                 this._numberOfAllTenders = numberOfAllTenders;
                 console.log('+++++++++++++++++++ number of tenders in db = '+this._numberOfAllTenders);
              },
              error => this._error_all_numbers = error
            );
```

When working with variables in your component that get values from observables, it can either be good to have a default value or, if necessary, use null checks with `*ngIf`:

```
*ngIf="_numberOfAllTenders"
```

You can also have your template subscribe to observables directly by using a syntax like this:

```
//in component
this._numberOfAllTenders = this._tendersService.getNumberOfAllTenders();

//in template
{{_numberOfAllTenders | async}}
```

This way `this._numberOfAllTenders` is of type `Observable<number>`.  And your template can subscribe to it with the `async` pipe, which calls `subscribe` in the background and retrieves the value.

Since Angular 4, you can use `async` inside `*ngIf` statements and assign the value to a local template variable:

```
<div *ngIf="_numberOfAllTenders | async; let myValue">{{myValue}}</div>
```

The main thing is an observable does not return a value synchronously and so you need to adjust your other code to work with that.  So if you are needing to use a value from one observable in order to call a second observable, you would need to look at chaining the observables together with `flatMap` or something like that:

```
firstObservable()
  .flatmap(dataFromFirst => secondObservable(dataFromFirst)
  .subscribe(dataFromSecond => //do something
```

Or if you need to save the value from the first observable before proceeding to the second:

```
firstObservable()
  .flatmap(dataFromFirst => {
      this.variable = dataFromFirst;
      return secondObservable(dataFromFirst)
   })
  .subscribe(dataFromSecond => //do something
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot. However, isn't there a way to wait for async call to finish first and then move on ?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to make an `observable....subscribe()` function synchronous where it finishes the subscribe before moving to the next line of code.